# In PHP, how to know how many mondays have passed in this month uptil today?

Tags: php, date, recurrence

Assume today is Feb 21, 2011 ( Monday ). It is the third Monday of this month. If date is given as input, How can I know how many Mondays have passed before it?

In PHP, how to know how many mondays have passed in this month uptil today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$now=time() + 86400;
if (($dow = date('w', $now)) == 0) $dow = 7; 
$begin = $now - (86400 * ($dow-1));

echo "Mondays: ".ceil(date('d', $begin) / 7)."<br/>";
```

works for me....

EDIT: includes today's monday too

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like a pretty straightforward division calculation. From the current date, subtract number of days past last monday (example: wednesday = -2), divide it by 7 and `ceil()` it to round it up.

EDIT: That will include the current monday in the number, returning "3" for monday 21st.

Comment: Works for Feb 21, but not for Feb 1.  If he had used 2/1/2011 as his example, you'd be returning "1" for Tuesday 2/1, (or if he's not careful he could be returning the number of Monday's in January).

Comment: My mistake, poor choice of words. By "date" I mean "day of the month". So subtracting one (because it's tuesday) from one results in zero, which rounds up to zero.

Comment: Right, the core formula is `ceil( day_of_month / 7 )`. But you need to subtract the days (-2 for wed in your example) since he asked for mondays.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, I believe that's mentioned in my answer. :)

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja: Agreed :) - Sorry for the poor wording in the second half of my comment. I was just trying to make it easier for me to understand what was going on here... perhaps it will help the next guy, perhaps not...

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the days until now and count the mondays:

```
$firstDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1, date("Y"));
$now = time();
$mondays = 0;
for ($i = $firstDate; $i < $now; $i = $i + 24*3600) {
    if (date("D", $i) == "Mon")
        $mondays ++;
}
```

Haven't tested this script

Comment: Using this approach, we may loop by getting "last monday" until `last monday`'s date belongs to previous month

Comment: Fixed the script, the j was supposed to be an n. It works now, but I would still prefer Kaivosukeltaja's solution, much simpler to do it with some basic math.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

 function mondays_get($month, $stop_if_today = true) {

$timestamp_now = time();

for($a = 1; $a < 32; $a++) {

    $day = strlen($a) == 1 ? "0".$a : $a;
    $timestamp = strtotime($month . "-$day");
    $day_code = date("w", $timestamp);
    if($timestamp > $timestamp_now)
        break;
    if($day_code == 1)
        @$mondays++;

}

return $mondays;
}

echo mondays_get('2011-02');
```

Hope this is of use to you! i've just rolled it up.

"Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Works OK afaik

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
//find the most recent monday (doesn't find today if today is Monday though)
$startDate = strtotime( 'last monday' );

//if 'last monday' was not this month, 0 mondays.  
//if 'last monday' was this month, count the weeks
$mondays = date( 'm', $startDate ) != date( 'm' ) 
         ? 0 
         : floor( date( 'd', $startDate ) / 7 );

//increment the count if today is a monday (since strtotime didn't find it)
if ( date( 'w' ) == 1 ) $mondays++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to find what day of the week is today, find the first such day of the month via some magic `strtotime()`, then calculate the difference between that and now in weeks. See below for a function that will take a `Y-m-d` formatted `date()` and return which weekday of the month it is.

Note: `strtotime` needs to be verbose, including "of" and the month: "first Monday of 2011-02" otherwise it [advances one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798261/issue-with-php-strtotime-function-when-using-ordinal-values/4798328#4798328). This bit me when I was testing edge cases.

Also added some display pepper which is completely optional but I felt like it.

```
function nthWeekdayOfMonth($day) {

    $dayTS = strtotime($day) ;

    $dayOfWeekToday = date('l', $dayTS) ;

    $firstOfMonth = date('Y-m', $dayTS) . "-01" ;
    $firstOfMonthTS = strtotime($firstOfMonth) ;

    $firstWhat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first $dayOfWeekToday of $monthYear", $firstOfMonthTS)) ;
    $firstWhatTS = strtotime($firstWhat) ;

    $diffTS = $dayTS - $firstWhatTS ;
    $diffWeeks = $diffTS / (86400 * 7);

    $nthWeekdayOfMonth = $diffWeeks + 1;

    return $nthWeekdayOfMonth ;
}

$day = date('Y-m-d') ;
$nthWeekdayOfMonth = nthWeekdayOfMonth($day) ;

switch ($nthWeekdayOfMonth) {
    case 1: 
        $inflector = "st" ;
        break ;
    case 2: 
        $inflector = "nd" ;
        break ;
    case 3: 
        $inflector = "rd" ;
        break ;
    default:
        $inflector = "th" ;
}

$dayTS = strtotime($day) ;

$monthName = date('F', $dayTS) ;    
$dayOfWeekToday = date('l', $dayTS) ;

echo "Today is the {$nthWeekdayOfMonth}$inflector $dayOfWeekToday in $monthName" ;
```