# strtotime function for year 2022 First Friday not working

Tags: php, strtotime

For year 2022 the strtotime "first Friday" query does not work when first Friday is first day of month.

E.G. For 2022 month equal 7:

```
$result = date("Y-n-j", strtotime('first Friday 2022-7');
```

returns string equal 2022-7-8 vs 2022-7-1.
For the "first day" the query returns string equal 2022-7-2
A similar wrong result occurs for month equal 4

What am I doing wrong? I am using PHP 7.3.33

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357490/getting-first-weekday-in-a-month-with-strtotime Seems relevant, specifically `"ordinal dayname " does advance to another day. (Example: "first tuesday july 2008" means "2008-07-08", see also point 4 in the list above).` Solution there, https://3v4l.org/fqWB3

Comment: `first Friday of 2022-7` should work